# Question about Cayley-Hamilton Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The Cayley-Hamilton theory states that every matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a root of its own characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)$. My thought is this,
since by definition $p_A(x) = \det(xI-A)$, filling in $A$ into this polynomial we obtain 
$$
p_A(A) = \det(AI-A) = \det(A-A) = \det(0) = 0. 
$$
What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: Check this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_bogus_%22proof%22:_p(A)_=_det(AIn_%E2%88%92_A)_=_det(A_%E2%88%92_A)_=_0).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that one. I guess filling out matrices in polynomials has always kind of confused me.

Comment: $p_A(A)$ should turn out to be the null matrix $O$, whereas you obtain the scalar $0$.

Comment: True, that seemed weird to me indeed.